# Basic Implementation of Google Play Billing in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Having a Python Kivy application, I decided to figure out how to implement paid access (one-time payment) to certain sections of the app through Google Play. Since I couldn't find any clear source of information for such situations and YouTube videos didn't help, I decided to try the 'trial and error' method, partially seeking guidance from ChatGPT.

The application was first tested without the code for paid access (which ChatGPT suggested) and it worked. After adding the code, it started giving errors that Python doesn't recognize Google modules. Therefore, it was decided to try testing through Google Play Console.

```
from google_play_billing import get_purchases, purchase_product  *#advice from ChatGPT*
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FadeTransition



Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'payedtext'  *#it's payed section*
                
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press:

                root.manager.current = 'menu'

<PayedScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'YOU PAID'

""")


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PayedScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
        settings_screen = SettingsScreen(name='settings')
        sm.add_widget(menu_screen)
        sm.add_widget(settings_screen)
        payed_screen = PayedScreen(name='payedtext')


        purchases = get_purchases()  *#advice from ChatGPT*
        if 'myapp.settings_button' in purchases:
            # User has purchased the button, show it
            payed_screen.add_widget(Button(text='My settings button'))
        else:
            # User has not purchased the button, show the purchase button
            purchase_button = Button(text='Purchase settings button')
            purchase_button.bind(on_press=self.purchase_settings_button)
            settings_screen.add_widget(purchase_button)


        sm.add_widget(payed_screen)
        
        return sm


    def purchase_settings_button(self, instance):  *#advice from ChatGPT*
        # Initiate the purchase flow
        purchase_product('myapp.settings_button', 'inapp')

        # After the purchase is completed, refresh the screen
        self.root.current = 'payedtext'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Basic creation of the AAB file through 'buildozer release' went smoothly. Signing the file with the .keystore also went well.

Added the file to Google Play Console - no errors were reported.

However, during testing, after downloading, the application crashes immediately after launch.

Questions:

1. Can anyone recommend sources where I can learn step-by-step implementation of in-app billing for Python Kivy?
2. Is there any way to test the application before uploading it to Google Play Console, but still have the Google services work and show if everything is functioning correctly?
3. How can I identify the errors that the downloaded application throws after launch, in order to understand how to fix them?
4. Could someone provide guidance on how to improve and correct the current code?

I was hoping that the uploaded AAB file to Google Play Console would result in a functional application.